# Simple Mouseover Function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have the following HTML:

```
img class="hoverContact"
img class="hoverContact"
img class="hoverContact"
```

And the following jQuery:

```
function highlightContact(ev) {
    $(this).addClass('lightblue');  
}

$('.hoverContact').mouseover(function(){
    highlightContact();
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use `this` inside `highlightContact` when the function has no context. Also, the function takes a paramater `ev` but you're not passing it in. Instead, pass `this` in from the mouseover function and reference `ev` instead of `this` in the highlightContact function:

```
function highlightContact(ev) {
        $(ev).addClass('lightblue');  
    }

    $('.hoverContact').mouseover(function(){
        highlightContact(this);
    });
```

Comment: @Thomas...so I added the same thing to remove it on mouseout...but what if I wanted it to stay on mouseclick?

Comment: @webwrks not sure i see what you mean - you want it to add the class on mousein, remove it on mouseout, and then when you click it locks it on or off so that mousein and mouseout don't affect it?

Answer (score 2):

use the `apply()` method so that **`this`** within your `highlightContrast()` function refers to the relevant img tag.

```
function highlightContact(ev) {
    $(this).addClass('lightblue');  
}

$('.hoverContact').mouseover(function(){
    highlightContact.apply(this);
});
```

Alternatively, if you don't need that `ev` at all - if all you are doing is adding that class, you can get rid of the `function highlightContact(){...}` completely and simply use:

```
$('.hoverContact').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('lightblue');
});
```

Comment: the reason why I separated it is because of the multiple instances of the hoverContact class